SKLearn - train_test_split
I am reading a list of pdf files and concatenating them as a unique string. Thereafter, I try to split the string into train_text and validation_text to train a LLM. Whey I use the train_test_split command from sklearn I get the following error:
ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.1 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters. I know it has something to do with the split by \n method. But whats wrong? and how to solve it?
text=""
pages = 0
for i in range(len(lista)):
    reader = PdfReader(lista[i]) 
    print("Arquivo:", i)
    pages += len(reader.pages)
    for j in range(len(reader.pages)):
        page = reader.pages[j]
        texto = page.extract_text() 
        text+= texto

print(pages)
##############################################################################

def clean_text(text):
    # Remove unwanted characters and noise
    text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)  # Replace multiple spaces with a single space
    text = text.lower()  # Convert text to lowercase
    return text.strip()


text = clean_text(text)

#############################################################################

# Split text into training and validation sets
train_text, validation_text = train_test_split(text.split("\n"), test_size=0.1)

